# Why do i get error "Type 10 authentication not supported" for postgresql 13 eventhough already in md5

Tags: postgresql

so i'm using 2 databases GUI to connect to database.

first is pgadmin4, second is aqua data studio

the problems occurs in the aqua data studio when i tried to connect it gave me that kind of messages "Type 10 authentication not supported".

I've read in some websites it says to change it to become md5, but i've already changed it to become md5 in the `host all all all md5` in the replication privilege.
in the pgadmin4, it works just fine, only in aqua data studio.

my friends wanted to access it from his local using aqua data studio so that's why i can't "force" everyone to use pgadmin4.
How do i resolve this?

btw this is my pghba file

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     peer
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     peer
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            scram-sha-256
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 scram-sha-256
host    all             all             all                     md5
```

#EDIT
I think i also needed to provide the authentication in the postgresqlconf
[postgresqlconf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZFfn.png)

Comment: Best guess is your friend is using an old version of Aqua Data Studio. Tell them to update.

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the password in the database is SCRAM-SHA-256 hashed. To confirm, query `pg_authid`:

```
SELECT rolpassword FROM pg_authid
WHERE rolname = 'youruser';
```

That is because the parameter `password_encryption` is set to `scram-sha-256`.

Now if you have a SCRAM-hashed password, PostgreSQL uses `scram-sha-256` authentication **even if it says `md5` in `pg_hba.conf`**. That is a compatibility feature that is supposed to make the transition to SCRAM easier.

To get your setup to work with MD5 authentication, you have to change the parameter `password_encryption` in `postgresql.conf` to `md5`, reload the database and set the user's password anew. Then you have an MD5 hashed password, and MD5 authentication will work.

The better thing to do, however, would be to upgrade your client software. It is never good to run old software.

Comment: Ah yes i tried the query that you gave and it says scram-sha-256, may i know where can i change the "password_encryption" to become md5? Tbh i also wanted them to upgrade it to newer version but it seems like "almost impossible" , so in my opinion i think it's better that i'm the one who give up to them :3 . fyi:i'm using postgresql-13 server in centos 7

Comment: I have added the information that parameters are commonly set in `postgresql.conf`.

Comment: Ok sorry Laurenz about that, i tried and already changed the postgresql.conf to become md5 and reload using pg_ctl restart also with pg_ctl reload and still got scram-sha-256 from the select query

Comment: Looking into my crystal ball, I see that you forgot to remove the comment in front of the `password_encryption` line.

Comment: Hello Laurenz, thankyou so much for sticking with me.. there is no # in front of the password_encryption line as you mention (i've provided the screenshot of the file )

Comment: Run `SELECT * FROM pg_settings WHERE name = 'password_encryption';` to see the `source` of your setting, and which line of which file you got it from.

Comment: already checked it and it's from postgresql.conf file and with that query pg_settings where name ='password_encryption' it said md5 :3

Comment: Then that is the value (column `setting`). Set the password again and you are good.

Answer (score 0):

After the above query reveal the password type, update the postgresql.conf and the pg_hba.conf to use md5.  Then reset the defaut password with
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'myPassword';